# Matching the exact string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two paragraphs:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Another text</p>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
if ( $("p:contains('Right text')") ) {
  alert("Matching!");
};


$( "p:contains('Right text')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

It should display an alert only if there's text `Right text`. But when you load the page, it displays everytime. Second part of the script should add underline to paragraph with `Right text` and it works - if it contains `Right text`, it has the underline.

Why my code doesn't work, although the selector is same? How can I display an alert if there's right text?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEvOWA?editors=1010

Comment: You need to check for `length` because even empty object is truthly value in javascript

Comment: `$('nonexistant')` is a jQuery object of length zero, but still an object and therefore still passes the naive `if`

Answer (score 2):

That's because the JQuery object will be converted to a boolean for the condition.
If it doesn't match, it will be a JQuery object of `length:0`, but still be converted into `true`. It only be converted into false if it was `0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined`.

Try this instead:

```
if ( $("p:contains('Right text')").length ) {
  alert("Matching!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("p:contains('Right text')")` always returns an array. This array is defined, so if you try to convert it to boolean, you always get `true`. Check the length of the array - it should be greater than 0.

Right code:

```
if ( $("p:contains('Right text')").length > 0 ) {
  alert("Matching!");
};


$( "p:contains('Right text')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

**Note:** if there's `Right text blah blah` it will have the underline too, because it contains `Right text`. If you want to check full content do

```
$( "p" ).each(function() {
    if ( $( this ).html() == "Right text" ) {
        alert( "Matching" );
        $( this ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a for-each and then get the string text of each tag p and use indexOf to find the position of the string that you want to match if the string is found the position is all's > -1 other wise it will be -1 in case it isn't a match

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().indexOf('code example') > -1){
        console.log($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: forgot to had the text must have copied a previous version of the code when testing never less thx for -1.

Comment: Your answer is unclear a bit (anyway, I'll keep +1 on). Do steps, e.g. 1. Blah blah blah. 2. Blah blah blah. 3. Blah blah blah. Don't stick the text together.